# slave on logical replication does not get update real time

Tags: postgresql, replication, insert, postgresql-12, pg-logical

I successfully started logical replication on a testing environment. I generate `insert` on the master for some 60K records using procedure. While the insert process is running, i monitor the slave using "`SELECT count(*)`" query. But the records are not adding. If I run the query after the insert has finished on the primary, the `SELECT count` works fine, all records between slave and primary are equal.

Is this normal behaviour ? I am expecting the slave and primary to be exactly the same at almost instantly.

Thanks

Comment: You will only see the changes on the standby, when the transaction on the primary is committed.

Comment: oh yes. make sense. It is waiting for commit. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you expect to see the counts progressively change for one or a few records at a time. But as a_horse_with_no_name mentioned, if the 60k rows that are being inserted are all happening within the same transaction, then you won't see the changes until that transaction completes.

Even on the primary server, you wouldn't see the counts change individually, only the total count change at the end once the transaction is committed. This is the nature of transactions, one of their properties is Atomicity (of the [ACID database principles](https://databricks.com/glossary/acid-transactions)), loosely meaning either all of the changes occur or none occur, there is no in-between.

Comment: yes. thank you. I was thinking it was auto-commit.